# Sending visual selection to neovim terminal

Tags: vim, neovim

I have adapted the following code which should send the visual selection to my Neovim terminal.

```
function! REPLSend(lines)
  echo a:lines
  " call jobsend(g:last_terminal_job_id, add(a:lines, ''))
  " call chansend(g:last_terminal_job_id, add(a:lines, ''))
  call chansend(g:last_terminal_job_id, a:lines)
endfunction

command! REPLSendLine call REPLSend([Get_visual_selection()])
" command! REPLSendLine call Get_visual_selection()

nnoremap <silent> <f6> :REPLSendLine<cr>

function! Get_visual_selection()
    " Why is this not a built-in Vim script function?!
    let [line_start, column_start] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
    let [line_end, column_end] = getpos("'>")[1:2]
    let lines = getline(line_start, line_end)
    if len(lines) == 0
        return ''
    endif
    let lines[-1] = lines[-1][: column_end - (&selection == 'inclusive' ? 1 : 2)]
    let lines[0] = lines[0][column_start - 1:]
    let lines = insert(lines, "%cpaste")
    return join(lines, "\n")
  endfunction
```

When I invoke the code with `f6`, `Get_visual_selection` correctly gets the text selected but the REPLSend(lines) function does not appear to get called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Debug it step by step. First, try `:call REPLSend([Get_visual_selection()])`. If that works try `:REPLSendLine`.

Comment: Thanks. Both `:call REPLSend([Get_visual_selection()])` and `:REPLSendLine` works. Seems to be a problem with `nnoremap <silent> <f6> :REPLSendLine<cr>`

Comment: Make it `nnoremap <f6> :REPLSendLine<cr>` (remove `<silent>`) to see the error.

Comment: @phd: removed `<silent>`. Checked `messages` but nothing there. How do I see the error?

Comment: I trimmed function `REPLSend` to just `echo a:lines` (I have `vim`, not `neovim`) and the code works for me, even after I pressed `<F6>`. I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use mappings like this:

```
" sending blocks (clearing previous output)
noremap <leader>tb (y)<C-w>wpa<C-l><CR><C-\><C-n><C-w>p)

" sending lines
noremap <leader>tl Vy<C-w>wpa<CR><C-\><C-n><C-w>pj

" sending visual selection
noremap <leader>ts y<C-w>wpa<CR><C-\><C-n><C-w>p
```

With these mappings, the terminal buffer should be in the next window position, but you can remap `<c-w>w` to `<c-w>j`, if the terminal buffer is always on the right, for example.